# Understanding DDD (services, aggregate, entities, repositories and specifications)

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

I'm starting with DDD and trying to apply in my current project, but as you can suppose I have thousand of questions.

Here I present a sample domain so I can make different question and serves as an exercise on which you can explain me how things can be made.

---

Our hypothetical system must take control of companies and what persons works on each one.

#### Domain.

- Company(id, name, address)
- Employee(id, name, surname, age)

A person can only work on a company and a company can have many employees working on it.

#### Operations

The system must allow to add a new employee to a company. For this it receives the company `id` and the `name, surname, age` of the new employee. There are some restriction to satisfy:

- There can not be another employee with the same `name, surname and age` in the company.
- The employee can be working in another company.

---

#### Questions

I have a mess in my mind :)

To implement the operation I'm thinking on:

- Service receives all the parameters.
- Service call `CompanyRepository->findCompanyById` to retrieve the company instance.
- Service creates a new instance of Employee using the specified parameters.
- Services calls `company->addEmployee` to attach the employee to the company.
- Within the `company->AddEmployee` check the new employee satisfies the conditions (specifications).
- Service calls `CompanyRepository->save(company)` to persist the company in addition to the employee.

Because `company+employee` is managed as a cluster (aggregate) I'm considering the company the aggregate root.

1. Is this a good implementation?
2. If I consider `company+employee` an aggregate, in the same way I described to save the cluster `company+employe`, must I retrieve all the related employees too  when I retrieve the company instance from repository ?
3. Respect specifications I can understand easily how to check, for example, if a employee name has more than 10 chars, but: how to check if the employee exists in the same company if the company has thousands of employees?
4. Can a specification call repository operations? and if yes, and the fact that considering company+employee a cluster is right, what would be the right place? `CustomerRepository->findEmployeeByName(idCompany, nameEmployee)` or better create a specific `EmployeeRepository`.

Comment: You have a rule in your fictional domain which cannot easily be made strongly consistent and that fictive rule wouldn't exist in a real world scenario: "There can not be another employee with the same name, surname and age in the company". That implies those values lives within the `Company` boundary... It's far simpler to enforce that a single person cannot concurrently be employed twice in the same company.

Answer (score 3):

## 1

What is *good* or *bad* is just an opinion. DDD shouldn't be a dogma and you can take the best of it and your own additions to build good software architectures.

## 2

No, company can either lazily-load employees (i.e. when runtime access the `Employee` property the first time after the company has been retrieved) or company can implement a `Load` method which also supports pagination to load only required employees.

## 3

You should implement this at repository level (for example `ICompanyRepository.ContainsEmployee(Employee)`) and use the underlying data mapper to perform this heavy operation.

Also, I tend to call specifications as pre-/post-conditions in repositories, because it's the only way to be sure that they will be fulfilled in all cases.

## 4

I would avoid it, but if you want to ensure a lot of domain rules, you'll need to use them in specifications. BTW, I wouldn't use repositories but I would use services instead.

The right place depends on the requirement. If you want to perform checks to be sure that domain objects are being stored in the repository in a valid state, I find no issue if you want to call an specification from within `ICompanyRepository.Add` or `ICompanyRepository.Update`, or `ICompanyRepository.AddOrUpdate`. The point here is you shouldn't verify object states both when they're stored in the repository and when they're retrievied. If your specifications and your code is reliable, if the repository has filtered domain objects and it has stored them in the underlying data store, you can be sure than read operations will get valid domain objects.

*Side note*: While you shouldn't model your domain based on the underlying data store (either relational, NoSQL, file system...), again, you shouldn't apply DDD like a dogma. If the underlying data store provides a better approach to define data constraints, I would try to use them instead of implementing complex specifications which might need to access the data anyway.

Your solution should be a balance of an optimal software architecture and runtime performance.

Comment: Hi Matias. Respect 3 my question is who is responsible to call it. Right, it can be done at repository but it is fine a specification call it or on a service side? Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. I get what you mean, but this is like saying that everything is always subjective and there's no fundamentally good or bad design. There are definitely good and bad ways of modeling specific domains.

2. Lazy-loading is usually a design smell indicating incorrect aggregate root boundaries. Also, an object model shall be optimized for commands, not queries (CQRS).

3. Careful here, data could be stale at any time. It's ok to check, but you have to rely on a unique database constraint during insertion to ensure uniqueness. You could also ask the `Company` AR if it's boundary is large enough.

Comment: 4.Double-dispatching can be done between a repository and a specification. That technique is discussed in the Evans book. However, a repository shall not be used to enforce domain invariants. That's the role of the domain and aggregate roots.

Comment: @plalx Yes, you're right about there're good and bad/wrong domain designs. My point is that OP shouldn't look for the dogma but work on his/her own reflections about what is a good design in his/her own domain. #1 has no easy answer in a Q&A format... It should need a full case study...

Comment: @plalx About #3 I'm absolutely agreed.......... This is why I added the side note after #4.

Comment: @plalx About the thing of invariants, since I'm not religious about DDD or any other paradigm or pattern, I would say that the solution should be a combination of letting repositories ensure that they won't store invalid objects, and some other specs triggered before the object is about to be handled by the repository.